# R - Roxygen2 doesn't see updated package definition when rebuilding & reloading

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

For instance, as a minimal working example, say I have built the following package `Test`:

```
# In R\Test.R :
#' @import methods 
#' @exportClass C
C <- setClass("C")
```

and now I change `setClass` to `setRefClass`:

```
C <- setRefClass("C")
```

when doing a 'Build & Reload' (in RStudio) I get the error

```
==> roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

* checking for changes ... ERROR

Error in getRefClass(class) : 
  class �C� is defined but is not a reference class
```

Well, of course it isn't a reference class *yet*, but in my updated package it will be! Checking the old class definition also throws up weird warnings:

```
> getClass("C")
Virtual Class "C" [package "Test"]

No Slots, prototype of class "NULL"
Warning message:
In .recacheSubclasses(def@className, def, doSubclasses, env) :
  undefined subclass "C" of class "refObject"; definition not updated
```

It appears Roxygen ignores my new definition of `C` and the old class definition still stands. How can I get Roxygen to focus on my new definition and for my rebuild to succeed?

(Note that this problem is not specific to `setClass` - I'm just using it as an example.)

**My setup:**

I have Roxygen set up in RStudio to run before I rebuild, so that my NAMESPACE file is updated automatically if my `@export`s etc change.

- Roxygen2 3.0.0

  - Using roxygen to generate (in RStudio):

    - Rd files
    - Collate field
    - NAMESPACE file
  - Automatically roxygenising when running (in RStudio):

    - R CMD check
    - Source and binary package builds
    - Build & Reload
- R: 3.0.2 (Frisbee Sailing)
- IDE: RStudio 0.98.490
- OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: Restart R - see the session menu. If you're making packages you should learn the restart R keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks @hadley, but does this mean I have to restart R before every Rebuild & Reload just so I can guarantee roxygen functions safely?! Currently, as a workaround, I'm manually unloading my package (by unchecking its checkbox under RStudio's 'Packages' tab) before a Rebuild & Reload. However, why are these workarounds even necessary? Why is roxygen not seeing definitions from my updated package?

Comment: Why are you re-building and reloading and not just re-documenting? Your problem sounds more like an S4 class caching problem, and you will need to restart to resolve that. I restart R probably hundreds of times a day. It is a very important technique for package developers.

Comment: It's because I'm still in the middle of writing my package, and so my code is still changing a lot and hence warranting a rebuild from time to time. I didn't realize you had to restart R so often - thanks for pointing that out. I was under the impression a Build & Reload in RStudio was as good as having restarted anyway.

Comment: And build and reload will restart R on completion - but if it fails to build the docs then it doesn't complete and hence doesn't restart.